# What does BlockingCollection.Dispose actually do?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

What does BlockingCollection.Dispose actually do?

Comment: I encountered issues with disposing blocking collection (e.g. release the Take last time), until I started to use CancellationToken, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5759866/1544054

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This allows the internal wait handles to be disposed of properly.

`BlockingCollection<T>`, internally, uses a pair of event wait handles, which in turn have an associated native `HANDLE`.

Specifically, `BlockingCollection<T>.Dispose()` releases these two handles back to the operating system, by eventually (through SemaphoreSlim->ManualResetEvent) calling the native [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211(VS.85).aspx) method on the two native `HANDLE` instances.

Answer (score 4):

Having a quick look with reflector reveals this...

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!this.m_isDisposed)
    {
        if (this.m_freeNodes != null)
        {
            this.m_freeNodes.Dispose();
        }
        this.m_occupiedNodes.Dispose();
        this.m_isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

and `m_freeNodes` is `private SemaphoreSlim m_freeNodes;` so it releases the SemaphoreSlim that are used internally.

Answer (score -9):

> Releases all resources used by the current instance of the `BlockingCollection<T>` class. ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267332.aspx))